# Problem with indefinite integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I introduce shift $t^5=2x -3$,but it doesn't help $$\int \frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{\left(2x-3\right)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}dx$$

Comment: Looks like that substitution will give you a rational integrand. What is the problem?

Comment: After shift i get a problem with second part of integration : $t^3/t^5+1$

Comment: Split the numerator and the first part will cancel, leaving a simple rational part that is easily integrable. The second part can then be handled with the substitution you have already proposed.

Comment: Try a partial fraction decomposition (it will get ugly).

Comment: What subtitotion to take to solve the second part ?

Comment: The answer will contain more than two partial decomposition i think there must be a way to simplify it

Answer (score 2):

$$J:=\int \frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{\left(2x-3\right)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}dx=\int\frac{dx}{x-1}-\frac12\int\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}=$$

Substitute in the second integral as you did:

$$t^5=2x-3\implies dx=\frac{5t^4}2dt\implies J=\log|x-1|-\frac54\int\frac{t^4\,dt}{\frac{t^5+1}2t}=$$

$$=\log|x-1|-\frac52\int\frac{t^3}{t^5+1}dt$$

Now do partial fractions:

$$t^5+1=(t+1)(t^4-t^3+t^2-t+1)$$

To decompose that you better know the roots of unity of degree $\;5\;$

Comment: Hm it's not the best solution,complex zeroes are ugly

Comment: @NikolaVidović It's not a matter of "best, good, bad..." solution: it is THE solution, unless I made some mistake. The complex zeroes aren't that ugly: they're simply the roots of unity generated by $\;\zeta_5:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}5}\;$ on the complex unit circle. What is somewhat ugly is the partial fractions decomposition, but there is no other option I can see. If it were some definite integral perhaps complex analysis could help.

Comment: I need solution with real numbers

Comment: @NikolaVidović And you'll have it, but in order to decompose that quartic you will have to find the two quadratic real polynomials into which it factors, and the only more or less acceptable way I know to do it, without wild guessing, is by means of the complex non-real roots.

Comment: The last integral can be expressed on closed form with the Incomplete Beta function.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from

$$I=\int \frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{\left(2x-3\right)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}\text dx$$

One substitution approach is $u=\sqrt[5]{(2x-3)^4},\,\text du=\frac 8{5\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}\text dx,$ which yields

$$I=\frac 58\int\frac{2u^\frac 14-1}{u^\frac 54+1}\text du$$

If $v^4 = u,4v^3\text dv=\text du$, then we get

$$I=\frac 52\int\frac{4v^3(2v-1)}{v^5+1}\text dv$$

With some partial fraction decomposition, we get

$$\frac 1{v^5+1}=\frac 1{v(v+1)}\left(\frac 1{v^2-\varphi v+1}+\frac 1{v^2+\frac v\varphi+1}\right)$$

where $\varphi^2-\varphi-1=0$, and thus

$$I=\frac 52\int\frac{4v^2(2v-1)}{v+1}\left(\frac 1{v^2-\varphi v+1}+\frac 1{v^2+\frac v\varphi+1}\right)\text dv$$

Now we are in the realm of relatively simple integral terms.